# python, importing function from other file which uses variable in the functions file

Tags: python, variables

I currently have a python program which imports a function from a file, but this function uses a variable which is stored in the file the functon is called from.

The code for the main function:

```
from second_file import second

while True: 
    print second(param)
```

The code for the second function:

```
 counter = 0
 def second(param):
     counter +=1
     return param + counter
```

When running the programm i get the following error:

```
local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment
```

So the question is, how can i get the "second" function to use this variable.

Comment: is there any reason that you inialize `counter` outside of the function?

Comment: if i set the counterinside the function it will get reset with each function-call right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with imports. In Python functions, you can call variables from a higher scope as long as it's read-only. If you write to the variable (like your `counter += 1`) it becomes local to the function and gives this error.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemis so is there a wac of changing the variable localy to then store it globaly(until the next call)

Comment: It's really hard to understand the problem you're having because I have no idea what the structure of your package is. Yes, there's almost certainly a way to retain that value. Global variables are not the answer, though.

Comment: @two-bit-alchemist ty for your help/answer, it works now using global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are modifying global variable you need to explicitly state that using

```
global counter
counter += 1
```

Otherwise here variable scope is limited to function and in this function scope, counter is not defined and hence the error.

Comment: the problem is, global doesnt help, the value wont increment/remain incremented when callingthe function the next time

Comment: That is the behaviour of global vairables, and this answers your question. What exact behaviour is required when you call the second function, can you show the output for 3-4 subsequent calls to second?

Comment: ty for the help, the global variables work now, i used them incorrectly the first time